# Please help identify this pre-1994 space opera paperback (a sequel) with a "human bullet" and a catgirl

Tags: story-identification

Around 1993-1994, certainly no later than the end of 1994, I purchased a paperback from a thrift store on Nantucket.  The cover was black; the title (in large white letters under a circular graphic) was two very short words, possibly with a "II" at the end, as this was a sequel to a previous book.  I'm almost sure the first word was "Star"; I thought the second word was "Cops" but that only turns up information about the 1987 BBC2 TV series.  The cover design including the typography made me think the book was printed in the late 1970s or early-to-mid-1980s.

The two main characters travelled around space in their own spaceship; I believe they were official agents for some kind of peacekeeping force.

The man was called a a "human bullet" or something similar; I got the impression that this was something like calling him a "paratrooper", designating the specific skill-set he brought to his occupation.

The woman was what would today be called a "catgirl" (though I don't remember if the book used that term):  a humanoid with visible feline traits.

The only part of the plot I remember was the somewhat surprising denouement when they retired and settled down as a couple, possibly even expecting a child.  It was surprising because I hadn't perceived much of a romantic relationship between them prior to that.

Can anyone identify this?

Comment: I read this novel too, and have been attempting to find the title. I remember the ship was called something like Doomstar or Darkstar. The captain was human, and the pilot was a catwoman. They were hired to rescue a princess whose brother (name was Harlan I believe). Harlan was a human bullet(warrior caste), who operated in a spacesuit/combat suit that could travel in space like a spaceship. Just like the Jedi, all the human bullets were betrayed and killed, except for Harlan. They rescue the princess, but she is brainwashed. At the end, the human captain and princess return to her home planet

Comment: I once knew a man from Nantucket, but he was very rude and I'd rather not get in contact with him again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [Doomstar](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7686070-doom-star---original-version) published in 1978 and [Doomstar Number Two](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7686083-doom-star-number-two---original-version), published in 1979 by  Richard S. Meyers (hat tip to @John S. for remembering the name) :

Rewritten and republished as [Doomstar](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7686073-doomstar---rewrite-version) and [Return to Doomstar](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7686085-return-to-doomstar---rewrite-version), both released in 1985.

> Larry -- commander of the Earth Ship Black Hole, an artificial man
>   with a heart of gold. Napoleon -- the sultry female feline and
>   tireless fighter desired and feared by all.
>   Harlan -- an invincible
>   human weapon, the space bullet waging a personal war against the
>   slavemasters.

There are two versions of each book, an original (left) and a re-written version (right)

[image: Original Version] [image: Revised Version]
[image: Original Version] [image: Revised Version]

Comment: If this answer was inspired by John.S then it's traditional to make a note of that in your answer.

Comment: The mention of the ship's name as 'Doomstar' by @John.S instantly evoked a memory of the second cover which features the filina. From there, ISFDB provided the author for specific searching.

Comment: As I said, it's traditional to mention that in your answer. I've edited in something that would be appropriate but you're free to roll it back, obviously.

Comment: The Doom Star Number Two cover certainly is close to the description in the original question. 

http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/c/cd/DMSTRNMBRT1979.jpg

Comment: That's the book - Doom Star Number Two, the 1979 cover.  The description of the first book makes what I remember of the second book make more sense.  Thank you!