# Novel with space suits made of strange material, disruptor knives that melt people, and nonhuman characters

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

I am looking for a science fiction novel I read at least 16 years ago, when I had a used paperback copy from a library or used book store.

One of the main characters was a person who was part of a military/police organization.  He flew a spaceship/personal space suit that I think was described as being made of stone, or a stone like material that was brittle and could be chipped into pieces.  During one part of the book, he had to escape his home and used a knife-like weapon (disruptor knife?) that melted people from the inside out if stabbed, and also decayed/melted wooden support beams or similar.

Another main character was some kind of cat person/alien.  She ended up being friends with the stone suit guy.  I think she was a pilot of some kind.  At the end of the book, someone built her a ship of her own, and they flew off together.

I am at least 60% certain the protagonist of the book was some human guy, but I've completely forgotten anything to do with his motivations.

Unfortunately, cat aliens and space suits are common google search results, and I haven't had any luck narrowing it down further.

Comment: If the book is Doom Star it has been asked about before. Have a look at [Please help identify this pre-1994 space opera paperback (a sequel) with a “human bullet” and a catgirl](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63785/please-help-identify-this-pre-1994-space-opera-paperback-a-sequel-with-a-huma) and see if it triggers any memories.

Comment: @JohnRennie I saw that one but wasn't sure about linking to it, since that question is specifically asking about the sequel.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be [Doomstar](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7686070-doom-star---original-version)?

> Larry -- commander of the Earth Ship Black Hole, an artificial man with a heart of gold.
>
> Napoleon -- the sultry female feline and tireless fighter desired and feared by all.
>
> Harlan -- an invincible human weapon, the space bullet waging a personal war against the slavemasters.

It's been more 30 years since I read it, but Larry was the main viewpoint character and came across as a normal-ish guy.  Napoleon was the catgirl and Harlan was an ex-military type they hooked up with early in the book.  He wore a hard shell space suit (described here as a "space bullet" but in my memory it was more blocky) and had a variety of weapons, though I don't recall a disruptor knife.

[image: original edition][image: revised edition]

Comment: I'm almost certain this is the book.  Everything seems to fit.  I've ordered a copy from Amazon to confirm as there's nothing available locally and I can't find an electronic copy.  I'll update this to answered as soon as it arrives.

Comment: @DapperSheep Any update? If this *was* the book you were looking for, it would be nice to accept the answer (checkmark on the left) to mark it as correct.